# Edit External User Profile

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users

I want my external users themselves to edit their profile esp their mobile number, their company etc.
Could anyone suggest me the easiest way to accomplish this. Should I develop an app ?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 or 2013? For **FBA**?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 online . What is FBA?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Active Directory data, please, take a look at the following article: [Synchronize user and group profiles in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx#Phase4)

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint online, user profiles are not supported for External users. But there is a hack thru which you can get a user profile, but it is not supported by Microsoft. See this blog for the hack => http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/profiles-and-pictures-for-office365-sharepoint-online-external-users/