# How does a Sharepoint External User update their profile?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am on O365 Government and want to manage both internal and external users on the same list. I am not a Site Collection owner, and make sites (subsites to the collection). I just found the below Discussion which states “user profiles are not supported for External users”. I invited myself to my External site, and don't see a way to update my profile. As seen in the below, there is no option to update. Pleasehelp

[enter link description here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164243/edit-external-user-profile)

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, external users cannot update their profile. This is by design as they do not posses a SharePoint Online license in that tenant.